# Adding a 3rd Party Ad Script to a React App

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

I received an Ad Script that i need to include in my react app. The script tag runs in the body of the code and should load an image.

This is the tag im trying to insert.

```html
<script type="text/adtag">
 <ins class='dcmads'           style='display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px'
   data-dcm-placement='N6246.289102DENTALPRODUCTSHOPPER/B27429766.334458108'
   data-dcm-rendering-mode='script'
   data-dcm-https-only
   data-dcm-gdpr-applies='gdpr=${GDPR}'
   data-dcm-gdpr-consent='gdpr_consent=${GDPR_CONSENT_755}'
   data-dcm-addtl-consent='addtl_consent=${ADDTL_CONSENT}'
   data-dcm-ltd='false'
   data-dcm-resettable-device-id=''
   data-dcm-app-id=''>
 <script src='https://www.googletagservices.com/dcm/dcmads.js'></script>
</ins>
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.doubleverify.com/dvbs_src.js?ctx=2974662&cmp=27429766&plc=334458108&sid=7942714&dvregion=0&unit=300x250">
</script>
```

Ive tried creating a component that inserts the tag as a child of a div

```js
function Script(props) {
    const ref = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {

        if (ref.current) {

            const fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`<div>${props.innerHTML}</div>`)

            ref.current.appendChild(fragment)

        }
    }, [ref])

    return <div ref={ref} />  
}
```

And I've tried a few other things like using dangerouslysetinnerhtml but nothing seems to work.

If Successful the below image shows the code that should be inserted into the body.

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWoKW.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I am experiencing the same problem. Wondering if you have found a solution.